# Sampling with replacement with multiple attempts

Tags: probability, sampling

Let us consider sampling over $N$ objects in a bowl. $Q$ sampling attempts are made, each attempt consisting in picking $K_i\leq N$ objects, with $i = 1,\dots, Q$. After each attempt, the objects are put back in the bowl.

How to calculate the probability that, after the $Q$ attempts, each object of the bowl has been picked at least once?

For example, let us assume $N$=4, $Q$=2, $K_1$=2, $K_2$=3. Let us denote the objects as (1,2,3,4). In the first attempt, there are ${4}\choose{2}$ = 6 possibilities, i.e. ((1,2) (1,3) (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)). In the second attempt, there are ${4}\choose{3}$ = 4 possibilities, i.e. ((1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,4), (2,3,4)). The set of all possible combinations is therefore given by $6 \cdot 4$=24 combinations. From inspection, I can see that 12 combinations out of the 24, are those who cover all the 4 elements. Therefore result is 12/24=1/2. But how to come up with a general formula??

Comment: Pl show what attempts you have made so far, and where you are stuck so that we can render tailor-made help.

Comment: For example, let us assume $N=4$, $Q=2$, $K_1=2$, $K_2=3$. Let us denote the objects as (1,2,3,4). In the first attempt, there are ${4}\choose{2} $ = 6 possibilities, i.e. ((1,2) (1,3) (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)).  In the second attempt, there are ${4}\choose{3}$ = 4 possibilities, i.e. ((1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,4), (2,3,4)). The set of all possible combinations is therefore given by $6 \cdot 4 = 24$ combinations. From inspection, I can see that 12 combinations out of the 24, are those who cover all the 4 elements. Therefore result is 12/24=1/2. But how to come up with a general formula??

Comment: Look up the classic coupon collector problem, and its variants. Also, put your above comments in the body of your question so that all may see.

Comment: Interresting but I kind of doubt that a general formula will be given. Since Ki can change in each attempt the formula will have 2+Q variables. The following link covers (as far as I can see) the special case where all Ki equals 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: I wonder whether there could be a formula for a special case different than the one you mentioned, for example when Q=2...

Comment: @Garbt Well... If you put further limits like: Q=2, N even, all Ki = N/2 there is a pretty easy formula... but that's kind of "far away from the original question" ;-)

Comment: I think it might be still very valuable for me to find a solution for $Q=2$, but without further restrictions on $K_i$ and $N$. Therefore $K_1$ and$K_2$ can be different.

Comment: After some headache, I think I have found a solution for $Q=2$. The probability that after $Q=2$ attempts each object has been picked at least once is given by ${K_2\choose N-K_1} \prod^{N-K_1-1}_{w=0}\frac{N-K_1-w}{N-w}$. It would be great to generalize it to whatever Q...

Comment: @Garbt I'm pretty sure your formula is wrong. For $K2=N$ the probabilty shall be 1 but your formula generates another result.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer **doesn't** answer the general question. It only covers the special case Q=2 that OP asked for in a comment.*

When $Q=2$ we have two attempts $K1$ and $K2$ where $1<=K1<=N$ and $1<=K2<=N$. Further, $K1+K2>=N$.

In the first attempt $K1$ unique numbers will be picked.

In the second attempt there will be $N-K1$ unique numbers and $K1$ duplicates (of the first attempt) to pick from. Further it's know that $K2 >= N-K1$.

So for the whole experiment to be a succes, we must pick all $N-K1$ unique numbers in the $K2$ picks. The number of combinations giving succes is then found as:

$$NumberOfCombinationGivingSucces = \binom{K2}{N-K1}$$

**Now consider the case where $K2>=K1$**

In this case the number of duplicates picked in the second attempt will be in the range "NumbersToPick - NumberOfUniqueNumbers" to "NumbersOfDuplicates". Or as a formula the range is from $K2-(N-K1)$ to $K1$. So we can calculate the total number of combinations like:

$$TotalNumberOfCombinations = \sum_{i=K2-(N-K1)}^{K1}{\binom{K2}{i}}$$

So with the restrictions a) $Q=2$ b) $K1+K2>=N$ and c) $K2>=K1$ the probability of picking all N numbers in the two attempts $K1$ and $K2$ is:

$$P = \frac{\binom{K2}{N-K1}}{\sum_{i=K2-(N-K1)}^{K1}{\binom{K2}{i}}}$$

Using the same principle the case $K2<K1$ can be calculated.

Comment: Many many thanks, it seems correct! In general, would it work by simply replacing condition c) with $K_2$ with $max(K_1,K_2)$, and $K_1$ with $min(K_1,K_2)$?

Comment: @Garbt No, there is a little more to it than that, I think. Consider the example N=5, K1=4, K2=1 (and K2=2, 3, 4, 5).

Comment: I read again your answer and I am a bit confused. Let's assume $K_1=2$, $K_2=3$,$N=4$. Objects are (a,b,c,d). Let's say, we pick (a,b) in the first attempt. The combinations for the second attempt are ( (a,b,c) , (a,b,d) , (a,c,d) , (b,c,d) ). The successful ones are the ones that contain (c,d), which are 2 combinations. According to your first formula, we obtain 3 successful combinations though! What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: @Garbt The formula is based on positions of unique numbers. So there are 3 combinations: (Unique, Unique, Dupe), (Unique, Dupe, Unique),  (Dupe, Unique, Unique). If you insert your example numbers the formula gives $$\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2}}$$ which is $$\frac{3}{3+3} = 0.5$$ The combinations in your example for K2 is: (1,2,3), (1,2,4),(1,3,4),(2,3,4). If K1 gave you (1,2) then K2 needs to give you (3,4). As you can see it happens in 2 out of 4 cases, i.e. P=0.5 - just like the formula. You get the same if you say that K1 gave (3,4) or any other K1 combination.

Comment: @Garbt With Q=2 your whole question can be rewritten like: You have a back with X blue coins and Y red coins. If you pick K random coins what are the probability that you pick all the blue coins. If you think about the problem like that it's easier (IMO)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, the rationale behind the formula is more clear now. Still, I haven't understood why I cannot replace $K_2$ with max($K_1,K_2$) and $K_1$ with min($K_1,K_2$)... Cases like $N=5$,$K_1=1$,$K_2=4$, and $N=5$,$K_1=4$,$K_2=1$ must give the same result...